# How to stop a tap event from propagating in a XNA / Silverlight game

Tags: xna, c#, silverlight

I have a game with Silverlight / XNA game where text and buttons are created in Silverlight while 3d is done in XNA.

The Silverlight controls are drawn ontop of the 3D and I dont want a click on a button to interact with the 3D underneath

So I have

```
private void ButtonPlaceBrick_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
```

But my gesture handling on the 3d objects still runs even though I have set handled to true.

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
         // Read the next gesture
         GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
         switch (gesture.GestureType)
```

How am I supposed to stop it from propagating?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to define a region that contains your controls and if the touch position is inside it, do nothing in your XNA code since the event is already processed by Silverlight controls.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the area button takes up on the screen?